# fill NaN values by previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a DataFrame with some NaNs:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[111, 222, 'apple'], [888, 444, 'pear'], [666, 777, 'pineapple'] [None, 444, None]])
>>> df
    0     1     2
0   111   222   apple
1   888   444   pear
2   666   777   pineapple
3   NaN   444   NaN
```

And I want to get such a df

```
    0     1     2
0   111   222   apple
1   888   444   pear
2   666   777   pineapple
3   888   444   pear
```

Comment: what should happen if a row is all NaN?

Comment: "888" and "pear" are not the previous values. What did you mean?

Comment: why would the 3rd column contain NaN?  ... it does not contain a number in any of the other rows

Comment: There are no rows with completely NaN values. When I talk about the previous value, I mean values where the value of column '1' of the row without NaN is equal to the value of column '1' in the row with NaN

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `ffill()` with a `groupby`

```
>>> df.assign(**df.groupby(1, as_index=False).ffill())
```

---

```
       0    1          2
0  111.0  222      apple
1  888.0  444       pear
2  666.0  777  pineapple
3  888.0  444       pear
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of using groupby and ffill will be to assign it back to the dataframe.

```
df[[0,2]] = df.groupby(1).ffill()
```